# Apache can't modify/create files in network share

Tags: php, linux, apache2, filesystems, privileges

I use Ubuntu 13.10 Server in a Virtualbox on a Windows 7 Hostsytem.
My code is mounted from Windows to /var/www

```
//192.168.1.2/code_share /var/www cifs username=USERNAME,password=PASSWORD,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

Then I installed symfony in /var/www/project with composer and when I try to access my Symfony-Page, I get this:

```
IOException: Failed to chmod file "/var/www/project/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.xml".
```

Why is it for apache not possible to access this folder?

Comment: What ownership and access rights does that folder/files have? Is the file system mounted with any umask?

Comment: All files/directories are 777 and dev:dev ("dev" is my user). The mount-parameter are listed in the original post

Comment: That's a quite insecure setup, but I guess you know that. But access right's are clearly not the issue then i guess...

Comment: I know it's not secure, but it's just for internal coding, so I can live with that.

Answer (score 1):

Apache cannot change mode (privileges) of files when files are owned by some other user (dev

on your box). You must change UID and GID to apache's. By the way remove double uid option from your mount command.

Apache UID = 33 ; GID = 33

```
//192.168.1.2/code_share /var/www cifs username=USERNAME,password=PASSWORD,iocharset=utf8,uid=33,gid=33,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

EDIT

1. Apache UID

   $ cat /etc/passwd | grep www-data | awk 'BEGIN { FS=":" } END { print $3 }'
2. Apache GID

   $ cat /etc/group | grep www-data | awk 'BEGIN { FS=":" } END { print $3 }'

Comment: To be honest this way you will get other problems, like dev user will have problems with those files. There is other way to work with Apache. Try to use [user dir](http://www.techytalk.info/enable-userdir-apache-module-ubuntu-debian-based-linux-distributions/). Mount share in your home dir with uid/gid=1000 and use Apache run as your user. It is very easy, and takes less than 3 minutes to configure.

Comment: It's actually the `php` process's user that needs access to the cache folder of the application. This user isn't necessarily the same as apache's. i.e. if he's using `php-fpm` instead of `apache-mpm` (where apache internally starts and manages the php process). In fact apache itself should usually *not* have write access to the application's folders for security reasons.

Comment: @nifr true :) Still it is a developer machine and environment. This kind of solutions, ruining separate environment, chrooted maybe, is a job for SuperUser ;)